# Remove duplication from WebVTT subtitles

Tags: python

I want to perform statistical analysis and index subtitles that are stored in the [WebVTT](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebVTT_API) (Web Video Text Tracks) format. Before I can do that I need to remove duplicated text since each cue can contain text from previous cues.

This duplication is a side effect of making the subtitled words appear closer to when they are spoken in the video. Instead of switching between long lines of text, you get a scrolling ticker effect that helps portray the flow of the conversation.

Here is an example of a WebVTT file that uses this method to display subtitles:

```
WEBVTT
X-TIMESTAMP-MAP=MPEGTS:900000,LOCAL:00:00:00.000

531729805
00:00:35.680 --> 00:00:35.840
And

2656472485
00:00:35.840 --> 00:00:36.240
And Ellie,

46078992
00:00:36.240 --> 00:00:37.400
And Ellie, here's

3869256835
00:00:37.400 --> 00:00:37.640
And Ellie, here's what's

954881102
00:00:37.640 --> 00:00:37.760
And Ellie, here's what's leading

2106168935
00:00:37.760 --> 00:00:38.120
And Ellie, here's what's leading
the

75332790
00:00:38.120 --> 00:00:38.360
And Ellie, here's what's leading
the news

62505917
00:00:38.360 --> 00:00:38.800
And Ellie, here's what's leading
the news this

1300648395
00:00:38.800 --> 00:00:39.520
And Ellie, here's what's leading
the news this morning

2785830416
00:00:39.520 --> 00:00:39.640
And Ellie, here's what's leading
the news this morning.

1208960359
00:00:39.640 --> 00:00:39.800
the news this morning.
>>

1485135460
00:00:39.800 --> 00:00:39.960
the news this morning.
>> Students

527624481
00:00:39.960 --> 00:00:40.280
the news this morning.
>> Students across

593869850
00:00:40.280 --> 00:00:40.640
the news this morning.
>> Students across the

2992386592
00:00:40.640 --> 00:00:40.760
the news this morning.
>> Students across the country

462963948
00:00:40.760 --> 00:00:41.120
>> Students across the country
are

2603260721
00:00:41.120 --> 00:00:41.520
>> Students across the country
are set
```

Tools like [Subtitle Edit](https://www.nikse.dk/subtitleedit) have a "Merge lines with same text..." feature but it only works when text is added to the end of the cue and ignores cases where part of the text has been removed from the beginning (e.g. at *1208960359*).

My attempt to create a solution using Python made use of [webvtt-py](https://pypi.org/project/webvtt-py/) to help read, modify and save the newly created WebVTT file. Now that I can modify the subtitles I need to remove new lines and '>>' symbols and convert the cues to single lines of text that don't duplicate. Maintaining accurate timestamps will allow me to insert the cues into a Lucene index with the search results providing relevant video timestamps.

My solution grew organically but turned into a bit of a mess and wondered if there was a better approach that could be made:

```
from webvtt import WebVTT, Caption
import os

vtt_show = WebVTT.read('show.webvtt')
vtt_modified = WebVTT()

caption_reset = False
previous_text = ""
new_cap_text = " "
new_cap_start = vtt_show[0].start
new_cap_end = vtt_show[0].end
new_caption = Caption(
    new_cap_start,
    new_cap_end,
    new_cap_text
)
for caption in vtt_show:
    caption.text = caption.text.replace('\n.', '.')
    caption.text = caption.text.replace('\n', ' ')
    caption.text = caption.text.replace('>> ', '')
    caption.text = caption.text.replace('>>', '').strip()
    
    is_new_line = False
    if caption.text.startswith(new_cap_text) and new_cap_text.endswith(caption.text):
        new_cap_end = caption.end
    elif caption.text.startswith(new_cap_text) and not new_cap_text.endswith(caption.text):        
        new_cap_text = caption.text
        new_cap_end = caption.end
        caption_reset = True
    elif not caption.text.startswith(new_cap_text) and new_cap_text.endswith(caption.text):
        new_cap_end = caption.end
        common_prefix = os.path.commonprefix([new_cap_text, caption.text])
        if common_prefix != "":
            new_cap_text = caption.text[len(common_prefix):]     
        is_new_line = True
    elif not caption.text.startswith(new_cap_text) and not new_cap_text.endswith(caption.text):
        if caption_reset:
            if new_cap_text != new_caption.text:
                new_caption = Caption(
                    new_cap_start,
                    new_cap_end,
                    new_cap_text
                )
                vtt_modified.captions.append(new_caption)  
                new_cap_start = caption.start
            caption_reset = False  
        
        new_cap_end = caption.end        
        words2 = caption.text.split()

        match_found = False
        removed_words = []
        while len(words2) > 0:
            removed_words.append(words2.pop())
            new_string = " ".join(words2)
            if new_caption.text.endswith(new_string):
                removed_words.reverse()
                new_cap_text = " ".join(removed_words)
                match_found = True
                break
        if not match_found:
            new_cap_text = caption.text
    
    if is_new_line:
        new_caption = Caption(
            new_cap_start,
            new_cap_end,
            new_cap_text
        )
        vtt_modified.captions.append(new_caption)  
        new_cap_start = caption.end      
        
    previous_text = caption.text
new_caption = Caption(
    new_cap_start,
    new_cap_end,
    new_cap_text
)
vtt_modified.captions.append(new_caption)  
vtt_modified.save('vtt_modified.vtt')
```

Comment: For the sample input, the code returns: "[<00:00:35.680 - 00:00:39.640: And Ellie, here's what's leading\nthe news this morning.>,
 <00:00:39.640 - 00:00:40.760: the news this morning.\nStudents across the country>,
 <00:00:40.760 - 00:00:41.520: Students across the country\nare set>]" There is duplication of text from one the end of one caption to the start of the next. It is not clear what the criteria is for merging and splitting the captions.

Comment: Are you sure you ran the code correctly? You should not be getting \n in the middle of the text since they are removed by lines 18 and 19.  This is the output I get:

"WEBVTT \n00:00:35.680 --> 00:00:39.800\nAnd Ellie, here's what's leading the news this morning.\n\n00:00:39.800 --> 00:00:41.520\nStudents across the country are set"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to move all of your code into functions, ideally with one purpose each.

It's doubtful that you should be mutating the text on string properties of the caption object. You should be manipulating bare strings, and once you're happy with the result, then make a new `Caption`.

Your current approach fails to preserve file metadata such as `X-TIMESTAMP-MAP`. From the object you have, `vtt_show`, it seems that this can't be helped with the current library as it doesn't load that metadata in the first place; so to fix this issue you'd need to modify or replace the library.

Convert this:

```py
    caption.text = caption.text.replace('\n.', '.')
    caption.text = caption.text.replace('\n', ' ')
    caption.text = caption.text.replace('>> ', '')
    caption.text = caption.text.replace('>>', '').strip()
```

into fluent style:

```py
def clean_caption_text(text: str) -> str:
    return (
        text
        .replace('\n.', '.')
        .replace('\n', ' ')
        .replace('>> ', '')
        .replace('>>', '')
        .strip()
    )
```

If performance during your overlap detection is a concern, you may want to investigate suffix trees; see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6026483/detecting-length-of-overlap-between-two-strings for some hints.